# Requirements.txt is much too big

Tags: python, django

For kind of a Hello World application I did this before deploying to heroku:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

and got over 50 dependencies. I figure that's a lot, even so I'd removed the redundant dependencies from setting.py so now it looks like:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app1'
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware'
)
```

What else can I do?

Answer (score 2):

The `pip freeze` command is for things you have installed through the `pip` utility.

It has nothing to do with the installed apps you put in the `settings.py`. Those are just apps for Django to use. The packages installed via `pip` are python packages used by your environment.

Removing packages through `pip` might break other projects you are working on or other utilities that need the packages installed in your "global" environment.
It is suggested that you use a separate `virtualenv` for every project you do with Python, so each has its own packages installations, own pip utility and python interpreter.

More here in `virtualenv`: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: and if the project is already created, can I reduce the number of dependencies or do I have to recreate it?

Comment: you can create a virtualenv, install only the dependencies you need for the current project, and point the IDE to use the new virtualenv instead of the global one.

Comment: I didn't mention anything about IDE, I'm using notepad.

Comment: if you are not using an IDE and instead code through a terminal window, activate the virtualenv through that terminal and then continue coding..

Comment: I still don't what's the answer: yes or no, do I have to re-create the project or not?

Comment: you need a deeper understanding of what virtualenv does = it "sets" the environment variables of your system to point to a certain python executable, pip executable and site-packages (different from the global one). once you activate it, you are working under this environment and your already existing project, when run under that envuronment, will work with its settings.